# TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null even tho its not null in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, react-redux, rxjs

So I am new to react and my code should play the audio when the value of props.play is true, but it keeps on saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null. Heres my code....

```js
import React from "react"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import firebase from "firebase";
import fire from "./firebase"
import { useHistory } from "react"


function AudioPlayer(props){
    if (props.play === "true"){
        play()
    }
    const [progVal, setProgVal] = useState("0%")
    function update(event){
        let duration = (event.target.currentTime/event.target.duration)*100
        setProgVal(duration)
        console.log(progVal)
    }

    function play(){
        document.getElementById('player').play() //over it says its null
    }

    function stop(){
        document.getElementById('player').pause()
    }
    return(
            <div className = "audio-wrapper">
                <div className = "audio-container">
                    <div className = "audio-box">
                        <audio id = "player" src = {"some music url"} name = "audioplayer" onTimeUpdate = {update}>
                        </audio>
                        <button onClick = {play}>Play</button>
                        <button onClick = {stop}>stop</button>
                        <div class = "progress_div">
                            <div class = "progress_holder" id= "prog_holder">
                                <div id = "progress_meter" style = {{width: progVal + "%"}}></div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}


export default AudioPlayer
```

Or is there any method? I actually want my code to play audio when the person clicks play in my another webpage.

Comment: Consider not using `document.getElementById` in react at all. Use a "ref" instead. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @evolutionxbox i saw some tutorials on ref, i still dont know how to use, can you give some example

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64980022/using-getelementbyid-in-react